# Database with either/or foreign key

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys

I have the following table where there will either be a `lDeviceID` or `mDeviceID`as the foreign key but not both. What is the best way to handle this? Would making the fields `nullable` suffice?

`eventID` is primary key.

```
Event(eventID, timeStamp, data, support, lDeviceID*, mDeviceID*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the two FK columns are nullable, then you must either put in a valid FK or a null. However, this doesn't handle the case where you try to put in both or neither. The only way to enforce that is to create an Insert/Update trigger which validates that one is null but not both and raises an exception is the validation fails.